# How to efficiently modify a numpy 3D array with millions of cells

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have a 3D array with millions of cells with values that are essentially labels. I have another 3D array of the same size and I need to insert different values to it, depending on the label of the corresponding coordinate on the labels array.

I am wondering if there is a better way to insert values to a 3D array with so many elements, other than a 3 dimension nested loop (which takes about 300 seconds to generate).

To give a more concrete example, I have `labelMatrix` , which is a 512x512x200 in size, and has label clusters from 1-100,000. I also have a list `labelMeanList` that has 100,000 elements corresponding to number of labels. Each such element has information about the mean value that should go to each voxel in the 3D label matrix, corresponding to its label value accordingly. There is a new `meanMatrix` of size 512x512x200 where I would insert the mean values accordingly. Right now this is how I implement it:

```
for x, y, z in itertools.product(range(xDim), range(yDim), range(zDim)):
   currentLabel = labelMatrix[x,y,z]
   meanMatrix[x, y, z] = labelMeanList[currentLabel].mean
```

Now as I said, this takes a long time to run. Can anyone think of a better way to implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what those things are with the `mean` attributes in `labelMeanList`, but this would go a lot better with an array of mean values. (Also, a 3-dimensional array isn't really a matrix.)

With an array of mean values:

```
means = numpy.array([x.mean for x in labelMeanList])
```

you could just do

```
meanMatrix = means[labelMatrix]
```

applying [advanced indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing) to select all the values in a C-level loop, avoiding bytecode interpretation overhead and wrapper object creation.

Comment: I was not aware of this operation means[labelMatrix]. Thank you, this works great. Can you refer to any theoretical material to explain how this operation works and what happens in terms of memory?

Comment: @GuyTal: See the ["advanced indexing"](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing) link. (I miss the days when you could look for the underline to spot a link.)